# How to hide or change mobile header logo with Additional CSS or custom PHP

Tags: mobile, custom-header, logo

I am trying to either add or completely remove mobile header logo on my site easisure.co.zw, the theme I'm using seems to not have settings for mobile header logo, so only the desktop version is showing my custom logo.

I tried to use this additional CSS but it's not working too @media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
#site-logo { display: none !important; }
}

Comment: Since this is specific to your theme, you could contact the theme author directly and see if they can provide the CSS.